# How to loop over two arrays and create a map in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, dictionary

I am new to Ruby and trying out few examples on [this link](https://learn.onemonth.com/ruby-tutorial-map-vs-each/).

Say, I have two arrays

```
Array1: ["square", "circle", "triagle"]

Array2: ["red", "blue"]
```

I want to create a map such as,

```
[{:shape=>"square", :color=>"red"}]
[{:shape=>"square", :color=>"blue"}]
[{:shape=>"circle", :color=>"red"}]
[{:shape=>"circle", :color=>"blue"}]
[{:shape=>"triangle", :color=>"red"}]
[{:shape=>"triangle", :color=>"blue"}]
```

Here is the code I have tried.

```
def processArray6(array1, array2)
    newMap = [array1].map do |entry|
    {
        shape: entry,
        color: "abc" # Should write another for-loop here to loop over array2
    }
    end
end

array1 = ["square", "circle", "triangle"]
array2 = ["red", "blue,"]

p processArray6(array1, array2)
```

Output for the above code:

```
[{:shape=>["square", "circle", "triangle"], :color=>"abc"}]
```

I am not very certain on how to loop over the array2.

I am from Java background and still trying to understand how an entire map gets returned from a function and how to process each element of an array and create a map.

Comment: What you have showed as the desired output is 6 separate arrays, each containing 1 hash. Is that really what you are after? Perhaps you mean one array containing 6 hashes? In that case it should be `[{...}, {...}, {...}, ...]`, and not `[{...}] [{...}] [{...}] ...`.

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If what you need is an array of hashes, where every hash has the keys `shape` and `color`, then you can use `product` between array1 and array2 and then just map the result of that:

```
array1.product(array2).map { |shape, color| { shape: shape, color: color } }
# [{:shape=>"square", :color=>"red"}, {:shape=>"square", :color=>"blue"}, {:shape=>"circle", :color=>"red"}, {:shape=>"circle", :color=>"blue"}, {:shape=>"triagle", :color=>"red"}, {:shape=>"triagle", :color=>"blue"}]
```

Comment: `flat_map` and then an array of a hash(?) seems odd instead of just `map` to a `{ ... }` hash.

Comment: Indeed, just got confused because of the `[key: value, ...]`. Thanks @tadman.

Answer (score 2):

The following will return an array of hashes

```
def processArray6(array1, array2)

array3 = []

array2.each{|color| array1.each{|shape| array3 << {:shape => shape, :color => color}}}

return array3

end


>> processArray6(array1, array2)
=> [{:color=>"red", :shape=>"square"}, {:color=>"red", :shape=>"circle"}, {:color=>"red", :shape=>"triagle"}, {:color=>"blue", :shape=>"square"}, {:color=>"blue", :shape=>"circle"}, {:color=>"blue", :shape=>"triagle"}]
```

Comment: Tip: Instead of creating an array and stuffing things into it, then returning the array, just use `map` instead.

Comment: good point, certainly product is the way to go, then map that.

Answer (score 2):

You want to compute the "product" of the two lists, which is actually really easy as Ruby has the [`product`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-product) function specifically for this:

```
KEYS = %i[ shape color ]

def all_shape_colors(shapes, colors)
  shapes.product(colors).map do |pair|
    KEYS.zip(pair).to_h
  end
end
```

[`zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-zip) is used here to key the two entries in each pair.

In practice it looks like this:

```
shapes = %w[ square circle triagle ]

colors = %w[ red blue ]

all_shape_colors(shapes, colors)
# => [{:shape=>"square", :color=>"red"}, {:shape=>"square", :color=>"blue"}, {:shape=>"circle", :color=>"red"}, {:shape=>"circle", :color=>"blue"}, {:shape=>"triagle", :color=>"red"}, {:shape=>"triagle", :color=>"blue"}]
```

Note the use of `%w[ x y ]` instead of `[ "x", "y" ]` as a way of expressing the same array with more minimal syntax. `%i[ ... ]` is the same but returns an array of symbols instead of strings.

You can actually go one further here and make a very generic method that does this combination for you on an arbitrary number of things:

```
def hash_product(**things)
  keys = things.keys

  things.values.inject do |s, options|
    # Compute product and flatten, necessary for chains > length 2
    s.product(options).map(&:flatten)
  end.map do |set|
    keys.zip(set).to_h
  end
end
```

Where you now use it like this:

```
hash_product(shape: shapes, color: colors)
```

That means there's no requirement for a fixed set of keys. Anything will work:

```
hash_product(hair: %w[ red blue green ], hat: %w[ white black yellow ], shoes: %w[ orange brown tan])
# => [{:hair=>"red", :hat=>"white", :shoes=>"orange"}, {:hair=>"red", :hat=>"white", :shoes=>"brown"}, ... ]
```

Comment: Thanks for Array.product suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

[Array#product](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-product) is commonly used here, but it returns an array (from which the hash is constructed), which could consume an excessive amount of memory if the two arrays whose product is being computed are large. Here's a way of obtaining the hashes without using `product` (or creating a temporary array by other means).

```
keys = [:shape, :color]
arr1 = ["square", "circle", "triangle"]
arr2 = ["red", "blue"]
```

```
arr1.each_with_object([]) do |shape, arr|
  arr2.each { |color| arr << keys.zip([shape, color]).to_h }
end
  #=> [{:shape=>"square", :color=>"red"},
  #    {:shape=>"square", :color=>"blue"},
  #    {:shape=>"circle", :color=>"red"},
  #    ...
  #    {:shape=>"triangle", :color=>"blue"}]
```

It's curious that there is no `Array` method that produces an enumerator that generates the elements in the array returned by `Array#product`. It's easy enough to make one. (See [Enumerator::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-c-new).)

```
class Array
  def product_each(arr)
    Enumerator.new do |y|
      each { |e| arr.each { |f| y << [e,f] } }
    end
  end
end
```

Then

```
enum = arr1.product_each(arr2)
loop { p enum.next }
```

displays:

```
["square", "red"]
["square", "blue"]
["circle", "red"]
["circle", "blue"]
["triangle", "red"]
["triangle", "blue"]
```

enabling us to compute:

```
arr1.product_each(arr2).map { |pair| keys.zip(pair).to_h }
  #=> [{:shape=>"square", :color=>"red"},
  #    {:shape=>"square", :color=>"blue"},
  #    {:shape=>"circle", :color=>"red"},
  #    ...
  #    {:shape=>"triangle", :color=>"blue"}]
```

without creating a temporary array.